# Localization of an Azure website to a specific culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, localization, data-annotations

I'm working in a ASP NET MVC 5 project with es-ES culture (Spanish). Everything was perfectly localized but lately we publish our application in Azure. Then we found out that there's not .NET Language pack for Azure. So, we need to find out a solution.

We are trying to add the Spanish 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' to the project or to the deploy manually but nothing works. The required validation is displayed in English.

But one thing that is strange is that the are some messages in Spanish, like the date or number type validation like (' El campo Fecha Inicio debe ser una fecha.'). Searching in the code I found out that there's a 'es' folder in the bin folder with some dll with Spanish translations, the DataAnnotations is missing. But I can't find out a way to add the DataAnnotations.

I read other  option is to overwrite the messages of the attributes or mess the code with .resx files. But I'm not sure if that's a good idea. What's the actual best solution?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I opted to follow this method:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/07/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx/

It was simple and effective. Even if the post is from the year 2009 and for MVC2 is valid for a MVC5 project.